# Why does python SimpleHTTPServer not work on localhost when there is no internet?

Tags: python, windows, http, simplehttpserver

I ran python -m SimpleHTTPServer to create a web server session (on Windows 8). This works fine using http://127.0.0.1:8000 or http://localhost:8000 UNLESS there is no internet connection. When there is no internet the (Chrome) browser stays blank. How to make the local server work regardless of whether there is external internet connectivity? Is this a Windows specific issue?

Comment: works fine for me with no internet ... bah maybe it does.. tbh im too lazy to unplug my internet and check but im 99.9999% sure it works :P ... ok now I am sure it works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is what I think it is, you're testing by unplugging the network cable or turning off your wireless card.

When there is no network, in many Windows versions, the entire network stack, or at least the user space part of it, goes away.

You might hunt up a *loopback adapter* pseudo net card and install that, which will give you an always active network connection; I believe Microsoft did make one available for Windows 7 and earlier, but I haven't looked for it on Windows 8.

Comment: and that would explain why it works fine for me as well :P

Comment: Thanks for explanation tsc_chazz. Actually, I didn't turn off the wireless card. I was simply in an environment where the wi-fi wasn't working. I had hoped by running from localhost that I would not be prevented from running a local web server even if there was no internet available. This was an annoying discovery that it didn't work.

Comment: Joran - would you mind explaining your comment? What works fine for you?  Using a different OS? Using loopback adapter? My question was about why localhost doesn't work when there is no internet.

Comment: julian - if you have a network connection but no connection from that network to the internet, you'll still have a network stack even if the internet is not live. Network stack depends on the network, not on connection from that network to the internet.